# Vue.js component nav active class only applies on second click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router

I have a menu component that is inside a view, this view is accessed by it's own route (/how-it-works). Inside this view I am loading the header component which looks like the following:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="top-menu">
        <li v-for="menu in menuItems" v-bind:key="menu.id" v-bind:class="{'active' : menu.active}" v-on:click="setActiveMenu(menu)">
            <router-link :to="menu.url">{{ menu.name }}</router-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="get-started">
        <router-link to="/">Get Started</router-link>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The problem is that whenever I visit this route, I can verify that `menu.active` is true but the `active` class isn't triggered. However, if I am already within the /how-it-works route, then it works as it should but only for that route.  It seems to not work navigating across routes.  The `setActiveMenu` function looks like this:

```
setActiveMenu: function(menu) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.menuItems.length; i++) {
        this.menuItems[i].active = false;
    }
    menu.active = true;
}
```

Lastly the menu array looks like this:

```
menuItems: [
    {
        name: 'How It Works',
        url: '/how-it-works',
        id: 1,
        active: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Page 2',
        url: '/',
        id: 2,
        active: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Page 3',
        url: '/',
        id: 3,
        active: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Page 4',
        url: '/',
        id: 4,
        active: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Page 5',
        url: '/',
        id: 5,
        active: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Page 6',
        url: '/',
        id: 6,
        active: false
    }
]
```

I'm guessing my issue is either with how I'm treating the active state on component creation, or some issue navigating between routes. What is the right way to manipulate the header?

Comment: If this is to display which route is active, maybe use the [built in activeClass](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class) option? [Also here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#linkactiveclass).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.. instead of adding a click event I used the `created` method built into vue.js:

```
created() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.menuItems.length; i++) {
        this.menuItems[i].active = false;
        if (this.menuItems[i].url === this.$router.currentRoute.path) {
            this.menuItems[i].active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still wondering if this is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't think these codes will fix the problem you mentioned. It just active one `<li>` in `created()` hook.